# NFS mount fails at boot time

Tags: freebsd, nfs

I have the following in `/etc/fstab` on FreeBSD:

```
venture:/usr/redacted    /usr/local/redacted   nfs     rw      0       0
```

This fails during boot. However, after boot, the following command succeeds

```
mount -t nfs venture:/usr/redacted /usr/local/redacted
```

Two related questions:

1) last time I rebooted at the console (this machine is in a datacenter), I'm pretty sure I saw an explanatory message at boot time regarding the failure to mount. I think it had something to do with resolving the hostname. However, this message does not appear in `/var/log/messages` with other boot-time messages; is there someplace else I should be looking?

2) Any thoughts about what could be preventing the hostname from resolving at boot time, but no problem 30 seconds later from the command prompt?

Comment: Maybe its trying to mount before a local name service of some sort is up? (Local DNS server, etc.)

Comment: Heh.  Good thought.  I was going to respond that "venture" is in the hosts file, but I checked and, no, it isn't.  The local DNS server is dnscache, started by svscan late in the boot process, so I bet that's the problem.  I'm adding venture to the hosts file for now and we'll see after next reboot whether that fixes the problem.  Meanwhile, I'm still interested in an answer (if there is one) to my logging question.

Comment: No thoughts on the logging issue. I just think that a better solution to your mount failure problem is to start the nfs client after any networking services. Worked for me in the past...
If that isn't an option, a dirty workaround that also helped me before is to add this to your `/etc/rc.local`: `mountpoint /usr/redacted || mount /usr/redacted`

Comment: @Joseph R: I'm not sure how to make a system service in /etc/rc.d start after a local service in /usr/local/etc/rc.d

Comment: Which version of FreeBSD are you using?

Comment: @davidcl: sorry for the late reply. The services should have a name starting with S##<name>  or K##<name>. The ## is a number that refers to the order they're started in; lower numbers being started first. So you just want to change the numbers in the names of the services to ensure that networking starts before nfs.

Comment: You can check other logfile like `/var/log/daemon.log` or just grep for `nfs` in any file in `/var/log`. It could be that the DNS was not up yet at the time when the mount was tried.

Comment: We found that on certain Ethernet switches, traffic was disabled for 45 seconds after the machine powered up, and FreeBSD booted quickly enough that some services like NFS mounting would fail.  Turning on the `portfast` attribute for the switch port was the best way to fix things.

Comment: try changing `rw` to `rw,bg`. The `bg` option causes it to try remounting if it fails at first, the issue is that fstab mounts are attempted before networking is even up (because they include your filesystem).

Comment: If you're using DHCP, it can take several seconds before the `/etc/resolv` file is populated with the proper nameserver info. Simply add `bg` to the mount options in your line, changing `rw` to `rw,bg`.

Comment: Try to use option `late` in `/etc/fstab` and put the hostname in `/etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 2):

The network sometimes isn't fully functional (e.g. DNS) before the mount is attempted. You can add options in `/etc/fstab` to mitigate this. Either or both may work for you (I use both):

```
venture:/usr/redacted    /usr/local/redacted   nfs     rw,late,bg      0       0
```

These are the `late` option (try later in the boot sequence rather than earlier), and `bg` (keep trying in the background).

Answer (score 0):

I had several servers that showed the same behavior, network/local resolvers not started when the NFS mount is being accessed. The solution was changing service start. Not sure about freebsd, but that should give you a starting point.

Comment: Rather than changing the order of the services (which is a _big_ change that may break other things), simply adding the server's details in `/etc/hosts` seems to be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can check kernel messages. In centOS or redhat, these logs are located in /var/log/dmesg.

It may happen that during boot, before network services are up, server is trying to boot NFS storage and it is unable to resolve remote host.

You can also check by changing start time of NFS service at last.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking in `/var/log/boot.msg`  and `boot.msg`,
they will contain the text you see on the screen while booting up.

My guess is it might have something to do with runlevel 3 versus runlevel 5,
and that you might be trying to nfs mount something listed in the `/etc/fstab` file before all other required services have been started.

Instead of using the hostname **venture** in `/etc/fstab` you can try using it's ip address instead.  That would quickly verify it is a hostname or dns lookup problem.  You might be able to fix this by adding venture and it's ip address in /etc/hosts, but that would only work if you know venture won't have its ip address by dhcp.